# How can I write a loop that increments a node position and its label within a certain range?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's the code I have so far. I'm using tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->,very thick] (-5, -5) -- (5, -5); %x-axis
    \draw[->,very thick] (-4, -5.5) -- (-4, 6); %y-axis
    \draw [step=0.5cm] (-4.9, -5.9) grid (4.9, 5.9);
    \node[thick] () at (-4,6.2) {$\textbf{y} $};
    \node[thick] () at (5.2,-5) {$ \textbf{x} $};
    \node[very thick, rotate=90] at (-5.3,0) {\LARGE{\textit{Cost}}};
    \node[very thick] at (0,-6.7) {\LARGE{\textit{Months}}};
        \node[very thick] at (-4,-6.1) {$ 0 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-3.5,-6.1) {$ 1 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-3,-6.1) {$ 2 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-2.5,-6.1) {$ 3 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-2,-6.1) {$ 4 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-1.5,-6.1) {$ 5 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-1,-6.1) {$ 6 $};
        \node[very thick] at (-.5,-6.1) {$ 7 $};
        \node[very thick] at (0,-6.1) {$ 8 $};
        \node[very thick] at (.5,-6.1) {$ 9 $};
        \node[very thick] at (1,-6.1) {$ 10 $};
        \node[very thick] at (1.5,-6.1) {$ 11 $};
        \node[very thick] at (2,-6.1) {$ 12 $};
        \node[very thick] at (2.5,-6.1) {$ 13 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-5) {$ 0 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-4.5) {$ 5 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-4) {$ 10 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-3.5) {$ 15 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-3) {$ 20 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-2.5) {$ 25 $};
            \node[very thick] at (-5.3,-2) {$ 30 $};
    \filldraw (-4,-4) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw[<->,very thick] (-4,-4) -- (4.5,4.5);%steps are 0.5cm, so path is (-4,-4) to (4,4)
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to add a bit more information about the expected result. It's hard to understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to find a simple way to number the grid lines in a tikz xy coordinate plane. I'm making linear function problems for my 8th grade Algebra class and I need some coordinate planes. JPi solved the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but my guess is that this covers it.

*EDIT* In response to OP's question, the syntax is as follows.  Consider `\foreach \y in {0,5,...,30} \node at (-5.3,{-5+0.1*\y}) {$ \y $};`  What that means is create a variable `\y` and make it run from 0 to 30 in steps of 5.  The `-5+0.1*\y` business is the y-coordinate of the node, so the first one is at -5. the second one at -4.5, etcetera.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->,very thick] (-5, -5) -- (5, -5); %x-axis
    \draw[->,very thick] (-4, -5.5) -- (-4, 6); %y-axis
    \draw [step=0.5cm] (-4.9, -5.9) grid (4.9, 5.9);
    \node[thick] () at (-4,6.2) {$\textbf{y} $};
    \node[thick] () at (5.2,-5) {$ \textbf{x} $};
    \node[very thick, rotate=90] at (-5.3,0) {\LARGE{\textit{Cost}}};
    \node[very thick] at (0,-6.7) {\LARGE{\textit{Months}}};
     \foreach \y in {0,5,...,30}
    \node at (-5.3,{-5+0.1*\y}) {$ \y $};
    \foreach \x in {0,...,13}
        \node[very thick] at ({-4+0.5*\x},-6.1) {$ \x $};
    \filldraw (-4,-4) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw[<->,very thick] (-4,-4) -- (4.5,4.5);%steps are 0.5cm, so path is (-4,-4) to (4,4)
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: JPi: thank you very much! this does exactly what I'm looking for! It's too bad that the \draw[step= ] doesn't include some automatic numbering command. If you have a spare moment, would you indulge a NOOB with a brief explanation of the \foreach  and \x, \y commands? Is \x and \y naming that variable so that I can give it a value later? What does the * do in the increment command {-4+0.5*\x}? Thanks again!

Comment: See my edit: hope that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

A small variation of the @JPi answer (+1)...

**Edit:**
I don't see any reasonable reason to draw axes from `(-5, -5)` to `(5, -5)` and from `(-4, -5.5)` to `(-4, 6)` and than point at `(-4,-4)` designate as diagram axis origin. It is much easier to draw axes from the origin at `(0,0)`.

So the difference in my approach and your MWE are in determinations of coordinates of all image elements. Also I remove all not needed nodes options and for `x` and `y` nodes styles use  syntax more consistent with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,very thick] (-0.8,0) -- node[below=12mm,font=\LARGE\itshape] {Months}
                  ++ ( 9.8,0) node[right] {$\mathbf{x}$};%x-axis
\draw[->,very thick] (0,-0.8) -- node[above=9mm,sloped,font=\LARGE\itshape] {Cost}
                  ++ (0,10.8) node[above] {$\mathbf{y}$};%y-axis
\draw [step=5mm] (-0.9,-0.9) grid (8.9, 9.9);
%
\foreach \i [count=\ii] in {0,0.5,...,6}
    \node[below] at (\i,-0.9) {\ii};
\foreach \i in {0,5,...,30}
    \node[left] at (-0.9,\i/10) {\i};
\filldraw (0,1) circle (1mm);
\draw[->,very thick] (0,1) -- (8.5,9.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: useful addition +1